# Displaying specific GitHub gist lines in Jekyll

Tags: markdown, jekyll, embed, gist, minima

I am trying to add specific lines of GitHub gist code in a Jekyll article. Using `jekyll-gist` I can embed the entire gist using the `{% gist <gist_ID> %}` format, however this displays the entire gist.

An alternative is to use `gist-embed` with HTML as follows:

```
<script
  type="text/javascript"
  src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gist-embed@1.0.4/dist/gist-embed.min.js"
></script>

<code data-gist-id="<gist_ID>" data-gist-line="X-X" data-gist-hide-footer="true"></code>
```

Although this produces messy results in Jekyll with double opening brackets.

Is there a way to use a `data-gist-line` argument in `jekyll-gist`? Or are there alternatives that work well with Jekyll markdown files?

Answer (score 0):

Albeit not the pretties solution, what works is to make a specific CSS exception for  `gist-embed`-generated code-blocks as follows:

```
td:not([id^="file-"]) # removes any borders around gist's line numbers
code:not([data-gist-id]) # get's rid of double inline-code formatting brackets
```

A non-HTML markdown solution with `jekyll-gist` would be prettier, but this gets the job done with a clean output.